# How do I create automatic div for objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I thought like 10 times before posting this question here. I know it's one thousand times covered this topic, but I'm stuck on this problem..

I have this JSON created by a php script and I have to fetch it inside a `div class="data"` in order to create sub `divs`  for each element and a `<hr>` for each object.

How would you do it?

Here is my JSON:

```
[
{
id_sensors: "1",
name: "First sensor",
value: "10",
status: "1",
battery: "100"
},
{
id_sensors: "2",
name: "Second sensor",
value: "11",
status: "1",
battery: "99"
}
]
```

example of the expected result:

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="id_sensor"> 1 </div>
    <div class="name"> First sensor </div>
    <div class="value"> 10 </div>
    <div class="status"> 1 </div>
    <div class="battery"> 100 </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="id_sensor"> 2 </div>
    <div class="name"> Second Sensor </div>
    <div class="value"> 11 </div>
    <div class="status"> 1 </div>
    <div class="battery"> 99 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? There are hundreds of thousands of tutorials on the web about creating DOM elements.

Comment: I tought like 10 times before posting here.. I know that the question is pretty easy and there are thousands of tutorials, but I can't really understand objects well. This would be for me, a occasion for learn. BTW i'm stuck on a switching from each element to object.

Comment: If you wan't to understand objects this might be helpful http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/

Comment: I would also recommend you to try it hard and think of your question in detail. So you're questions would become more precisely. Right now it simply looks like you wan't others to do the work for you.

Comment: if any of the below answers solved your problem, marking one as the answer would be appropriate :)

Comment: Thanks for remembering me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have tagged jquery, here is my solution (untested)

```
$.each(json_array, function(key, val){//iterate array
  $.each(val, function(key, val){//for each array element (in this case, an object) again iterate thru object property name(key) and value
    $(".data").append('<div class="'+key+'">'+value);//make a div appropriately
  });
  $(".data").append('<hr>');//then insert an <hr> after it
}); //you may want a logic to prevent the last <hr> being drawn
```

EDIT: Since a bunch of other people made and tested pretty much the same thing I did, I went ahead and completed the code. http://jsfiddle.net/p98pp6za/ and a fiddle

```
var json_array = [{id_sensors: "1",name: "First sensor",value: "10",status: "1",battery: "100"},{id_sensors: "2",name: "Second sensor",value: "11",status: "1",battery: "99"}];

$.each(json_array, function(k, v){//iterate array
  $.each(v, function(key, val){//for each array element (in this case, an object) again iterate thru object property name(key) and value
    $(".data").append('<div class="'+key+'">'+val);//make a div appropriately
  });
  if(json_array[k+1])$(".data").append('<hr>');//then insert an <hr> after it (but not the last one)
});
```

Please note that this solution should provide a more robust approach, and be able to handle almost any object name/value pair, than other solutions provided to this question.

Comment: really thank you for your help! I'm getting: [object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement]
[object HTMLSpanElement]

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to generate html

```js
var str = '[{ "id_sensors": "1", "name": "First sensor","value": "10","status": "1","battery": "100"},{"id_sensors": "2","name": "Second sensor","value": "11","status": "1","battery": "99"}]';

var arr = $.parseJSON(str);
var temp = '';
$.each(arr, function(index,value){
  
  temp += '<div class="id_sensor">'+ value.id_sensors +
          '</div><div class="name">'+ value.name +
          '</div><div class="value">'+value.value +
          '</div><div class="status">'+ value.status+
          '</div><div class="battery"> '+value.battery+
          '</div><hr>';
});

var desireHtml = '<div class="data">'+temp+'</div>';

alert(desireHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try this solution and u will get your html

Answer (score 0):

just try this.,

```js
var myJSON = [
{
id_sensors: "1",
name: "First sensor",
value: "10",
status: "1",
battery: "100"
},
{
id_sensors: "2",
name: "Second sensor",
value: "11",
status: "1",
battery: "99"
}
];

$.each(myJSON,function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(index,val){
        $(".data").append('<div class="'+index+'">'+val);
    });
    if((i+1) != myJSON.length){
        $(".data").append('<hr>');
     };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
    </div>
```